# How can I import the "starter project" of the Play Framework into Eclipse? (Once I have downloaded it from the official website.)

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I would like to use the "Play" Framework on the IDE Eclipse for the first time. Therefore, I have downloaded the Java [starter project](https://www.playframework.com/download).
The problem is that, when I try to import it on Eclipse (File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace), I have the following error message "No projects are found to import".

I think it is because I haven't compiled the project and also because I do not have a .project filetype in my directory.

But when I follow the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD5w6KPtRlg&index=2&list=PLYPFxrXyK0Bx9SBkNhJr1e2-NlIq4E7ED), it does not work (even though I have tried to do it very carefully). I have spent 9 hours on this problem, I am rather new to programming, and I would appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The project is a gradle project so instead of importing it as existing project import it as a gradle Project

[image: gradle import]

Comment: OK, interesting answer, thank you. Now, I indeed see my "starter project" in Eclipse IDE. I am still a bit puzzled because in my tutorial, the teacher managed to import this "starter project" as a regular project. I don't know how he does that...

In addition, he then teaches how make a "Hello World" program with this "starter project" and if I have a Gradle project (instead of a regular one), maybe I will not be able to follow his tutorial anymore (because I will not have the same basis as his...)

Comment: @Susan295 I don't know how he did it but you can only import projects that have the .project file from eclipse if you chose to import existing projects from general. if you import other "types" of project eclipse will create the .project file for you (witch does nothing other than save some eclipse stuff). So it should be possible for you to follow the rest of your tutorial I suppose.

Comment: @Susan295 also if this answer helped you pls accept it

Comment: OK. I am going to see if the "Hello World" works with my Gradle Project.

Comment: I didn't have time to try it yet